# How to add & call Jwave and SVM in android-studio

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio, svm, libsvm

i try to use JWave function from this link
https://github.com/cscheiblich/JWave/blob/master/src/jwave/TransformBuilder.java
to extract features from the image

then the result will inserted into SVM training function
SVM from this link
https://github.com/yctung/AndroidLibSvm

How to add Jwave into android-studio
and how to call it ? How to send result from JWave to SVM training function

Comment: Post what you have tried - this isn't a code factory. We're here to help not to do your work for you.